# Fallo array fputcsv en PHP

Tags: php

estoy teniendo problemas al crear archivos csv con fputcsv. 
El caso es que recorro la base de datos mientras muestro las columnas y las guardo en el csv, pero en el bucle, también hago una llamada a una función la cual retorna un string. Hago un array_push para añadirlo al array que contiene las filas y me aparece un error:fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, integer given.
Os dejo el código para que me entendáis mejor:

```
$resultados = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll();

//Consulta SQL
                json_encode(array('response' => 'true'));
                mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
                $codificacion = mb_internal_encoding();

                try {
                    //Fichero
                    $archivo=fopen(getcwd()."/assets/log/".$nombre_fichero."_".$date.".csv","a+");
                    //Cabecera
                    fputcsv($archivo, $cabecera, $delimeter);
                    foreach ($resultados as $line) {  
                        $direcciones = $this->direcciones($token, $line, $archivo, $codificacion);
                        $lines = array_push($line, $direcciones);
                        fputcsv($archivo, $lines, $delimeter);//Aquí me da el error en el parámetro 2       
                    }
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    fputs($archivo,"Error al crear fichero CSV-> Error: ".$e->getMessage().PHP_EOL);
                }
                fclose($archivo);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-merge.php):

```
foreach ($resultados as $line) {  
    $direcciones = $this->direcciones($token, $line, $archivo, $codificacion);
    $lines = array_merge($line, $direcciones);
    fputcsv($archivo, $lines, $delimeter);
}
```

Saludos!

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por contestar!! No me sirvió el array_merge, me sale un error diciéndome que el parametro 2 tiene que ser un array...

Comment: De nada, agrega a tu pregunta un var_dump de $line y otro de $direcciones